# React18 with webcomponents causing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property shadowRoot of #<Element> which has only a gette

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component

I have a react18 application written in pure js (not ts). I've imported a webcomponent from another project that causes the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property shadowRoot of #<Element> which has only a getter`

```js
class ExampleComponent extends HTMLElement {

    shadowRoot
    
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
    }
    ...
}


window.customElements.define('example-component', ExampleComponent)
```

Does anybody know why this happens? Sorry I can't give you full code example due to company legals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was that `shadowRoot` should be named to `#shadowRoot`. Just add a `#` to shadowRoot. Don't ask me why but this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

With `shadowRoot` you define a property

But `attachShadow()` both ***creates*** AND ***returns*** `this.shadowRoot`

It is your (React) Build step that complains, doing it in native code is fine (but senseless)

```js
customElements.define('example-component', class extends HTMLElement {
    shadowRoot // unrequired
    constructor() {
        super()
          .attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
          .innerHTML = `Hello Web Component`;
    }
})
```

```html
<example-component></example-component>
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but why is that senseless?

Comment: because ``attachShadow`` sets (and returns) ``this.shadowRoot`` by default